# JDBC Batch in case of error

Tags: jdbc

I was wondering what happens to statements after a statement that turns up an error. I already know the statements before go through, but I was wondering what happens to the ones after.

Comment: This depends on the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...) and whether you are using autocommit or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I already know the statements before go through,

Maybe, or maybe not, depending on precisely what you mean by "go through".

> but I was wondering what happens to the ones after.

That depends on

1. whether AutoCommit is enabled,
2. the value of a setting like `continueBatchOnError` in MySQL Connector/J, if such a setting exists for the JDBC driver being used, and
3. the implementation-specific behaviour of the JDBC driver in the absence of (2), above.

Comment: Lets say autocommit is enabled, and I put three separate updates in a batch, the second one throws an error. Does the third update affect the database?

Comment: It still depends on how a given JDBC driver was written. The only way to know for sure is to try it with the particular driver(s) you intend to use.